# Create hive table from file stored in hdfs in orc format

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to know if its possible create a hive table from a file stored in hadoop file system (users.tbl) in ORC format. I read that ORC format its better than text in terms of optimization. So I would like to know if its possible create a hive table using `stored as orc tblproperties` and `location` attributes to create a table from the hdfs file but in orc format.

Something as:

```
create table if not exists users
(USERID BIGINT,
 NAME STRING,
 EMAIL STRING,
 CITY STRING)
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
LOCATION '/tables/users/users.tbl';
```

Insted of text:

```
create table if not exists users
    (USERID BIGINT,
     NAME STRING,
     EMAIL STRING,
     CITY STRING)
     ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE 
     LOCATION '/tables/users/users.tbl';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that in only one step. The create table statement doesn't process the data, just specify the format and the location.

My suggestion is that you create a temporal table using the "STORED AS TEXTFILE" create statement and create the final table using ORC as storage format (using an empty location).

Then insert in the "ORC table" all the rows from the temporal "text table".

```
Insert [overwrite] table orcTable select col1, col2 from textTable;
```

**Insert Overwrite** will replace all the data in the table with the new data. If you only want to add new data you will use "Insert table . . ."

After the import you could delete the temporal "text table".

Comment: ..I do not think temporal table is there in hive...create an external and give  location to where you text file is there..from this external   table just run insert select to orc table..and you have orc table in place.

Comment: It is temporal because it is only used to insert the data into the final table, and after that very probably you will want to delete it. But I´m agree that is not a "temporal" table like in other relational DB that delete the table automatically when the user session is closed.

Answer (score 2):

1.Create a table in hive.

```
 create table MyDB.TEST (
 Col1 String,
 Col2 String,
 Col3 String,
 Col4 String)
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat';
```

2. Load data to the table.

```
 LOAD DATA INPATH '/hdfs/dir/folder/to/orc/files/' INTO TABLE MyDB.TEST;
```

Answer (score 1):

just create your table on existing data like below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable
(
col1 bigint,
col2 bigint
) 
STORED AS ORC
location '<ORC File location';
```

Please refer this Link

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/179897/hive-table-creation-from-orc-format-file.html

Answer (score 1):

How about just create your table on top of your location, and use `msck repair table table_name`, so your data will be loaded into your table ready for querying.

Comment: This doesn't work when there is a Date field issue.